# IDE For html5 development

Tags: html, ide

I need IDE for Windows that can show result in real-time,like Espresso on Mac OS X does. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It does not do it real time, but I suggest using Aptana Studio for HTML5 developing. You just need to save and then refresh your browser.

Comment: I would suggest eclipse, aptana is built on top of eclipse and adds a lot of unnecessary plugins.  Standard eclipse with WTP (built in web tools) will give you everything you need.

Comment: In espresso you even not used to save it it updates just as you updates your code,that's what i want